# Inverting bootstrap row behaviour for sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need items in a sidebar vertically on big screens and horizontally on small screens.

But using bootstrap's row, it does the opposite.

Is there a simple way to inverse the behaviour to meet my requirements?

I dont want to use javascript for this simple design.

[image: vertically instead of horizontally]
[image]

index.html:

```html
<div class="container" id="mainContainer">
   <div class="col-md-4" id="sideBar">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8" id="mapContainer"></div>
</div>
```

css/main.css:

```css
#mainContainer {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
}
    
html,
body,
#mainContainer,
#mapContainer {
   height: 100%;
}
    
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   #sideBar {
      width: 300px;
   }
   #mapContainer {
      width: calc(100% - 300px);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div class="container" id="mainContainer">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4" id="sideBar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-8" id="mapContainer">map here</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xcqasno/

Comment: This does not work in my chrome.
Now the sidebar is always on the side (even on xs size) and the items still stack wrong.

Comment: Use col-xs-12 for a "vertical result"

Comment: That was the trick! I did not think about giving it 12 on big screen and less on smaller screens!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class like hidden-xs, this hides the content on small devices. Therefor you need to add another div with the content horizontal with the classes hidden-md hidden-lg witch hides the horizonal content on big screens.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont want to have everything duplicated in DOM. I accepted the other answer because it omits that problem!